How does the concept "RESTful API" origin?
How does the concept "RESTful API" origin?
I find below explanation on the Wikipedia which talks about REST:

REST has been employed throughout the software industry to create stateless, reliable web-based applications. An application that adheres to the REST architectural constraints may be informally described as RESTful, although this term is more commonly associated with the design of HTTP-based APIs and what are widely considered best practices regarding the "verbs" (HTTP methods) a resource responds to while having little to do with REST as originally formulated—and is often even at odds with the concept.[2]

So, it seems to me the concept REST which originates from Roy Fielding's dissertation has less relationship with the concept "RESTful API", so how should I understand the RESTful here if it doesn't refer to the same REST in Roy's dissertation?


how should I understand the RESTful here if it doesn't refer to the same REST in Roy's dissertation?

As a general rule, "RESTful" doesn't mean REST so much as "more like REST than what we were doing otherwise".
For example, in the web services world circa 2002, "RESTful" is a contrast to SOAP.  See, for example, Giving SOAP a REST by Amit Asaravala (2002).

The most common variation on "RESTful" that I see today is derived from the use of that label in the Rails community around the time of the 1.2 release.
So you might look at Rails Routing from the Outside In, or Designing RESTful Rails Applications.
It may also be useful to review REST: I Don't Think It Means What You Think It Does.

RESTful APIs leverage HTTP methods (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) and use URLs to access and manipulate web resources. The key principles of REST include a client-server architecture, stateless interactions, cache ability, a uniform interface, and optional code on demand. This approach has become the standard for web services due to its simplicity, scalability, and flexibility.
For more info refer to these sites -

https://blog.readme.com/the-history-of-rest-apis/
https://restfulapi.net/

